# Error when trying to generate workflow report

Tags: list, workflow, reports

I want to generate workflow report. So I choose my list, then Workflow settings -> view workflow reports -> Activity Duration Report -> I choose location to save file with report and when I click OK it give me error:

> The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

In my list I got about 900 items. How can I generate report? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try by increasing list view threshold limit in central admin-->application management-->select the web-application -->general settings -->resource throttling-->list view threshold limit

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to Central Admin. Is there any other possibility?